# MySQL specific unique constraint only on specific values

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have a table with these fields:

id, field_a, field_b, status
I have a unique constraint on (field_a, field_b, status)

I'm using the status (mapped as Integer) to manage also a soft delete so, when I need to mark an item as DELETD, I will update the status on the corresponding value.

In this way I will be able to create a new row with the same values for field_a, field_b values but with a different status.
But in this logic there is a problem: I will have a constraint unique violation if I will deleted an item that was already deleted.

For example:

1. INSERT ("Element A" "XXX") -> I will have: 1, Element A, XXX, 1 Status OK;
2. DELETE 1 -> I will have: 1, Element A, XXX, 1 Status DELETED;
3. INSERT ("Element A" "XXX") -> I will have: 2, Element A, XXX, 1 Status OK;
4. DELETE ("Element A" "XXX") -> I will have an error because the unique constraint will be violated (Element A, XXX, 1 Status DELETED already exist);

Is it possible to have the same constraint but, regarding the status, I would like to use only a specific value (in this case only OK)?

Comment: No, not possible. The set of values must be unique. To me it seems that field_a, field_b is not unique - you need one more field besides the status to make things unique.

Comment: You should consider to define another field with a custom hash, using there the logic that fit your needs. Es. You could prefix the hash of the field of the constraint with the info of the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any component of unique index expression for a row is equal to NULL then this row is treated as unique anycase (because one NULL is not equal to another NULL). So:

**Variant 1.** Use NULL for `status` column value as a mark that the row is deleted.

[fiddle for variant 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62a906dc7c0b7edd5d10504188ede37a)

**Variant 2.** Use an expression which converts DELETED status to NULL in the index expression (if your server version allows index by an expression):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx
ON tablename (field_a, field_b, (CASE WHEN status = 'DELETED' THEN NULL ELSE status END))
```

[fiddle for variant 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e99ff5b0f040f3d6cee8ef8d137f864a)

Comment: I'm creating the table using   UNIQUE KEY `UKjbv46ywarhqhq9i4oicu0p44v` (`field_a`,`field_b`,`status`).
Is it wrong? I used a sql client tool to generate this script. What's the difference between my approach and UNIQUE INDEX approach that you suggested with the varian 2 solution?

Comment: @Safari *What's the difference between my approach and UNIQUE INDEX approach that you suggested with the varian 2 solution?* Your solution uses `status` value as-is. My solution replaces `'DELETED'` value with `NULL` and does not alter any other value. *Is it wrong?* This is not wrong in general (for example, it can be useful for queries improvement), but does not solve your task.

Comment: yes.. my comment was just an additional help request! I'm not a DB expert so my question was: How can I change my sql script to support your variant_2? Just removing myUNIQUE KEY UKjbv46ywarhqhq9i4oicu0p44v (field_a,field_b,status) and adding your CREATE UNIQUE INDEX command?

Comment: @Safari True. But you must ensure that your server version allows the index by an expression (i.e your MySQL is 8+ version). If your MySQL version is older then variant 1 is the only option.